# Как натягивать landing page на wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, вёрстка

Как известно, в landing page содержатся много блоков, каким образом сохранять эти блоки, в качестве страниц, рубрик, записей?
Еще бывают моменты типа калькулятора, каким образом добавлять данные для него и куда создавать в админке новый тип записей, но это не совсем записи, это просто поля, так что не понимаю как.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO. Так как вы здесь только появились, ознакомьтесь с правилами создания вопроса в нашем сообществе по адресу http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking . Это поможет нам всем с пониманием вашего вопроса, а также улучшит ваше понимание того на какие вопросы здесь отвечают, как, а также в каком виде их задавать чтобы получить ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Это называется "вёрстка". Верстаешь страницу как тебе надо.

См http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2

Или берёшь [готовую тему](https://wordpress.org/themes/). Сейчас 90% тем имеют на морде лединг. Но не у всех нормальный функционал. У нек для этого используются плагины-конструкторы страниц (зло это). Одна из последних используемых мной тем с хорошим функционалом и без конструкторов: [Himalayas](https://wordpress.org/themes/himalayas/)

PS. Не забываем про [механизм дочерних тем](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B)

Comment: Вы не поняли вопроса. Landing-page - одна страница. На одной странице содержатся много блоков. Каким образом сохранять их? Делить блоки на страницы или рубрики, а данные в блоках на записи? или как-то еще

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю что такое леддинг. Блоки - это вёрстка. А куда с них ведут ссылки или откуда в них поступают данные (а НЕ сохраняются с леддинга!) - это другой вопрос. Но всё это можно делать 10тью разными способами. Тут не место это всё описывать, поэтому поставь тему и посмотри как что в ней реализовано. Это один их хороших способов. И изучай документацию. К теме в тч.